# Silex: How and why to use testing

Tags: php, testing, silex

The documentation on testing is not really clear to me. It says you can use testing to check whether my pages and my system works correctly.

In my opinion, that would mean it could check whether all rights are used properly or something like that. But I don't understand why I'd put so much time in coding the testing part.

I hope someon could explain and convince me why I should use testing, and as a second part: HOW I should use it!

So, as an example, this could be my basic index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$routes = $app['controllers_factory'];

$routes->match('/', function () use ($app) {
    return 'Hello';
});

$app->mount('/', $routes);
$app->run();
```

Could you give me an example or adjust my route and give some testing with it. And please don't use the examples from the documentation: they don't make sense to me and that's the whole reason why I'm asking it here.

### EDIT

So, both your comments were helpfull. I think I'm starting to understand why it might be usefull. Now, all I need is an example to fully understand it. Let's say I've got this route:

```
$routes->match('/user/login', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class)
        ->add('username', TextType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 3,'max' => 3))),
            'label' => 'Username',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Docent afkorting'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5))),
            'label' => 'Password',
            'required' => 'required',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'input-field', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'Wachtwoord'),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'label'),
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Login',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
        ])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $user = new User();

        if($user->login($data['username'],$data['password'])){
            return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('home'));
        }
        else{
            return $app['twig']->render('form.twig', [
                'content' => 'Incorrect username or password<br><br>',
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('form.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
})->bind('user.login');
```

What would I have to do to have a proper test?

Comment: Say you have a contact form. It has 3 fields. You want to validate the input data. So far so good - easy enough to understand, right? Now, this validation part.. that's the tricky part where tests help you. Is it faster for you to manually input bad / good data and simply check with your eyes if it's all good or is it easier to type a command that will give you green or red light? Now, contact form is an easy example. Multiply that by 500 different routes - what's faster? A human testing manually, or computer doing it automatically? That's one of the reasons why you write tests.

Comment: Tests are useful when you want to test a functionality. You design a test with example input and expected output. Any further changes in the code can cause the test to fail, meaning the new code is doing something wrong. You might want to search something about **Test-driven development**.

Comment: Okay! That's clear, I've updated my question with an example route that logs a user in. All straight forward, nothing special. Could you answer me on how to proper test this route?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at the *[Create your own framework tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html)*. It explains why testing is a good thing and shows some examples. Also, there is very good reference to [this great talk](http://www.slideshare.net/avalanche123/clean-code-5609451) in the official testing docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with software tests, you may be wondering why you would need this. Every time you make a change to your application, you have to test it. This means going through all the pages and making sure they are still working. Functional tests save you a lot of time, because they enable you to test your application in usually under a second by running a single command.

Source:
https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/testing.html#why